# How best to handle metadata lookup?

Tags: managed-metadata, taxonomy, lookup-column

I have a query regarding how I should best handle uploading documents into SharePoint (currently WSS) where the Taxonomy asks for client code for all documents.  The problem I have is that we have say 10k+ client codes so rendering a scrolling list of these to pick the code is a no-go!

How would you suggest I get around this issue?  Split the codes up perhaps/custom coding to modify the new and editform.aspx files?

Answer (score 2):

You can create custom field types that use picker controls or use OOTB BDC fields (also a picker control) to search for data.

I would warn you against creating custom new/edit form pages. It can be done but its a pain in the... to get working.

Answer (score 1):

How about using an [ajax autocomplete lookup column](http://sptoolbasket.codeplex.com/Wiki/View.aspx?title=SharePoint%20-%20Autocomplete%20lookup%20field%20with%20AJAX)? So you don't have to modify any aspx files.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are definitely looking at creating a custom newform/editform.  The [jQuery library for SharePoint Services](http://spservices.codeplex.com/) might also be something that you can leverage.